# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with np.load()

Tags: python, numpy

I got a problem that the np.load() doesn't work suddenly.

When I run a code like this:

```
import numpy as np 

a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print a

np.save('test',a)
p=np.load('test.npy')
```

There is a problem: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I used np.save() and np.load() many times before it worked well. I don't know why it suddenly become wrong. Please help me to see where is the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: What line is giving you that error?

Comment: its seems to work fine here,

Comment: Didn't you overwrite `np.save` or `np.load` ?

Comment: Maybes your array is saved as strings like `"1", "2", "3" `. Try mapping it to an int. `a = map(int, a)`

Comment: Please improve your question. When you say "code like this" yet the code above works for others then I suspect the difference is critical. Please post the ACTUAL code or better yet a portion that throws the error and the line number and error details. Finally, make sure you haven't set np.load, np.save or np.array to a string object in your code because the error you reported basically means you are using a string as a function.